# Dockerfile won't execute on ubuntu

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Running docker ce 19.03.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 on Lenovo Thinkpad

Narrowed my problem to a line in Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["bash","-x","/var/lib/postgresql/tendenci_startup.sh"]
```

which produced the following error:

```
myusuf@ubuntudt:~/$ docker logs cdb08f7ebdd1
bash: /var/lib/postgresql/tendenci_startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

The same Dockerfile worked flawlessly on a macOS Catalina 10.15.2 with the same version of Docker. Here the content of /var/lib/postgresql/tendenci_startup.sh:

```
echo
processes="memcached postgresql"
echo "== Starting up application processes =="

for p in $processes
do
    echo == starting $p
    service $p start
done

#su postgres -c "bash -x /var/lib/postgresql/configure_tendenci.sh"



# Run nginx in the foreground to keep the container alive
nginx -g "daemon off;"
service --status-all
date
```

I've read a few postings about line endings and the like - those weren't helpful.

```
The content of my working directory:
myusuf@ubuntudt:~/work/docker/ws1$ ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 2 myusuf myusuf 4096 Feb  1 00:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 myusuf myusuf 4096 Jan 29 23:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf  871 Feb  1 00:16 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf 3310 Feb  1 00:16 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf  789 Feb  1 00:16 configure_postgres.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf 3440 Feb  1 00:16 configure_tendenci.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf 2295 Feb  1 00:16 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf  437 Feb  1 00:16 generate_cert.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf 1923 Feb  1 00:16 nginx_mysite.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf 2159 Feb  1 00:16 sfportengineers.ddns.net.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf 3272 Feb  1 00:16 sfportengineers.ddns.net.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf   43 Feb  1 00:16 tendenci.code-workspace
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusuf myusuf  338 Feb  1 00:16 tendenci_startup.sh
```

```
The Dockerfile:

myusuf@ubuntudt:~/work/docker/ws1$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04
LABEL maintainer="projectMaintainer"

###########################################
# for apt to be noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true

###########################################
# preesed tzdata, update package index, upgrade packages and install needed software
RUN inetutils-ping tcpdump apt-file wget libtelnet-utils telnet && apt-file update; \
  add-apt-repository universe && apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib postgis \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


COPY .bash_profile configure_postgres.sh tendenci_startup.sh configure_tendenci.sh /var/lib/postgresql/
RUN chown postgres /var/lib/postgresql/.bash_profile
COPY .bashrc /root/

COPY nginx_mysite.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_mysite.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx_mysite.conf
COPY sfportengineers.ddns.net.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/sfportengineers.ddns.net.crt
COPY sfportengineers.ddns.net.key /etc/nginx/ssl/sfportengineers.ddns.net.key

EXPOSE 80/tcp 443/tcp


RUN service --status-all; service postgresql start; sleep 10; service --status-all; \
  su postgres -c "bash /var/lib/postgresql/configure_postgres.sh"; \
  service postgresql stop; service --status-all; \
  echo "postgres ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers; \
  rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

CMD ["bash","-x","/var/lib/postgresql/tendenci_startup.sh"]
```

```
The build, run, and error:

docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t local/tendenci "."
docker container run -dt --name tendenci -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -p 443:443 -v var_lib_postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql local/tendenci

bash: /var/lib/postgresql/tendenci_startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your full Dockerfile and describe your folder structure, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Please post the whole Dockerfile. Fundamentally, it's failing because the file doesn't exist. As to why it would exist with the same Dockerfile elsewhere, that's a mystery without a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

you mount a volume on `/var/lib/postgresql` from `var_lib_postgresql/`

`docker container run -dt --name tendenci -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -p 443:443 -v var_lib_postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql local/tendenci`

are you sure `tendenci_startup.sh` is inside your folder `var_lib_postgresql/` ?

Comment: tendenci_startup.sh was inside the volume. I should mention that this configuration ran flawlessly on the macOS, it just won't run on Ubuntu18.04

Comment: Why would it be inside the volume?  Mounting the volume will hide everything that's in the underlying image.  It'd be better to store scripts that you need to use to start the container somewhere separate from your data.

Comment: Your verify that your script can be executed ?